# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python

```
puzzle = [[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4'], [' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8'], [' 9', '10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', 'X']]

remaining = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

for line in puzzle:
    for element in line:
        current_line = str(puzzle.index(line))
        current_element = str(element)
        curr_input = str(input('Enter number for row ' + current_line + ' and column' + current_element + " from " + str(remaining) + "\n\n"))
        puzzle[puzzle.index(line), element] = curr_input
        remaining.remove(curr_input)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

for line

```
puzzle[puzzle.index(line), element] = curr_input
```

But neither of those indices are tuples! That is why I use the puzzle.index function! What is going wrong?

Comment: sorry, I copied the code wrong

Comment: `puzzle.index(line), element` is a tuple. What were you hoping to index with that tuple?

Comment: `[puzzle.index(line), element]` at this line `puzzle.index(line)` will give you index but you are also passing `element` by comma separation which is making the index as tuptle.

Comment: puzzle is a list of list. I was hoping to index the "element" index of the inner list with index "puzzle.index(line)"

Comment: @AndrewSalter: index each list individually. `puzzle[outer_index][inner_index]`.

Comment: Shit. I just remembered the syntax is list[outer][inner] isn't it?

Comment: Beat me to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the index of a list basing on a tuple index:

```
puzzle[puzzle.index(line), element] = curr_input
```

you should use:

```
puzzle[puzzle.index(line)][line.index(element)] = curr_input
```

The error is because the way you tried to access is a implicit convertion to a tuple.

edit:

for clarification, just go on your python and try:

```
>>> 1,2      
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your Error is in this line

```
 puzzle[puzzle.index(line), element] = curr_input
```

you cant access the element of list of list like that...